# How can I locate old sheet music if I know the author, title and copyright info?

Tags: history, copyright

In doing research about one of my ancestors, I found a record of a hymn that he wrote and received a copyright for, back in 1914. I'm interested in locating a copy of the sheet music, but I have no idea where to start -- this appears to be the only song that he had copyrighted, and Google searches are not providing any useful information.

What I have is an entry in the [Catalog of Copyright Entries](https://books.google.com/books?id=uv83AQAAMAAJ&pg=PA1475&lpg=PA1475&dq=%22that%20glad%20day%22%20%22david%20reid%22&source=bl&ots=m7fiSActoP&sig=FGWUqr8yzCbCSCguiQk2YTlHHnk&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiuipKipOrcAhXDqlkKHZwMBGoQ6AEwAHoECAAQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22that%20glad%20day%22%20%22david%20reid%22&f=false) published by the Library of Congress:

[image: Catalog entry]

```
THAT GLAD DAY; hymn, words and music 
  by D. Reid; unacc. 4to. [24032 
    (C) Nov. 21, 1914; 2 c. Nov 24, 
  1914; E 349678; David Reid, Boston.
```

With this information, how would I go about locating the music?